# Remix IDE File Explorers is missing

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

I have no idea what happened, but all of a sudden, the file explorers in remix ide is gone. I tried all I can to recover it, including restarting it, switching back and forth between new and old versions, reinstalling it and rebooting the pc. None of these worked. I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can get it back! Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From release 0.11.1 auto-migration of files is turned off, so you will need to migrate your files manually to be able to see them again.

See the release notes, here -> https://medium.com/remix-ide/remix-release-0-11-1-cdb3063327d

*"Automatic migration of files to Workspaces has been turned off. So you cannot see your current files unless you migrate them."*

Comment: They should have put a bigger warning in the empty space.

Comment: Completely agree! Or they could have created a default workspace and just... automatically migrated the files there.