# Is Remix compiler broken?

Tags: remix

I was able to use remix, an online compiler for solidity. However, I can't anymore. When I go to the website, I cant even see the files under "file explorer", it is just empty.

When I click "New File" on the home screen, it doesn't even create one. What is happening?

Website:

https://remix.ethereum.org/

Comment: It's not broken, I used it yesterday. Clear your browser cache or something...

Comment: As of v0.11.1, you need to migrate your files. -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96583/remix-ide-file-explorers-is-missing